# Generic method syntax

Tags: java

I have forgotten the syntax for a generic method:

```
public static void swap <T> (T a, T b)
{...}
```

And I don't find anywhere some example.What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Here I have written a sample piece which i have used for my application. You can get an idea from this.


        public <C>void addColumn(Cell<C> cell, String headerText,
              final GetValue<C> getter, FieldUpdater<DocumentType, C> fieldUpdater) {
            Column<DocumentType, C> column = new Column<DocumentType, C>(cell) {
              @Override
              public C getValue(DocumentType object) {
                return getter.getValue(object);
              }
            };
            column.setFieldUpdater(fieldUpdater);
            column.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
            getTable().addColumn(column, headerText);
            getTable().setColumnWidth(column, 10, Unit.PX);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static <T> void swap(T a, T b) {..}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your typed parameters before the return type (void in your case).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.4 (see [TypeParameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#323928))